# telnet connection is timed out via telnetlib while working via cmd

Tags: python, python-2.7, telnet, telnetlib

I'm trying to use [Telnet](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) to connect to my remote device. When using telnet via *cmd* I got no issues, and the prompt looks like this

[image]

As you can see, it requires:

1. *"user>"* (answer "su") and then
2. *"password>"* (answer "1234") and then the prompt is
3. *"mp4100#"*

Upon writing "?" (even without enter) the prompt spits out a huge string.
I'm trying to mimic this, but nothing seems to be working...

```
import telnetlib

HOST = "172.17.174.241"
user = 'su'
password = '1234'
time_out = 2
name = "mp4100"
prompt = name + '#'

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, timeout = time_out)
tn.set_debuglevel(100)

tn.read_until("user>", time_out)
tn.write(user + "\n")

if password:
    tn.read_until("password>", time_out)
    tn.write(password + "\n")

#tn.read_until(prompt, time_out)
tn.write('?')

print tn.read_all() # shouldn't this write the string that the prompt wrote?
tn.close()
```

When I run this it just freezes.

---

**Edit**: I added timeout to the connection, and that is where it freezes. The device won't connect via the script, even though through *cmd* it has no problems

---

Code edited a bit to show what I'm doing right now. Output after adding `tn.set_debuglevel(100)` (What are the legal values for this function? didn't see it in the doc / spyder help)

```
Telnet(172.17.174.241,23): recv '\xff\xfb\x01'
Telnet(172.17.174.241,23): IAC WILL 1
Telnet(172.17.174.241,23): recv '\xff\xfb\x03'
Telnet(172.17.174.241,23): IAC WILL 3
Telnet(172.17.174.241,23): recv '\xff\xfc\x01'
Telnet(172.17.174.241,23): IAC WONT 1
Telnet(172.17.174.241,23): recv '\xff\xfc\x03'
Telnet(172.17.174.241,23): IAC WONT 3
Telnet(172.17.174.241,23): recv '\n\r'
Telnet(172.17.174.241,23): recv '\n\ruser>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Could you try `Telnet.set_debuglevel(debuglevel)`?

Comment: adding output now

Comment: It seems now that what I was missing was a '\n' after the '?'